# why my jenkins is stuck while checking out a project via SVN?

Tags: maven, jenkins, build

I have downloaded eclipse and with it I have checked out a project available via SVN, the project is named "Simulation" and is available at an address, with eclipse I can do everything but my main job is to build that project via Jenkins so I have created a maven project that gets the code from SVN: `some_address/svn/Simulation` and I configured it to build every 2 minutes but 30 minutes passed and here is the log from build #1:

```
Started by user %USERNAME%
Started by timer
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\simulation
Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\simulation
Cleaning local Directory .
Checking out http://some_address/svn/Simulation at revision '2019-02-26T09:30:18.376 +0100' --quiet
Using sole credentials devops/****** in realm ‘<http://some_address> VisualSVN Server’
```

now, I am able to ping successfully to that address and like I said before, I checked out the project with eclipse
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to tell that I copied the log from build #1 because he is still stuck there